# Why do I get a 404 error and what does no Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' mean?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting

What does it exactly mean and how do I solve it?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:106 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase
App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
     at f (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase.js:1:73499)
     at Object.i [as auth] (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase.js:1:73757)
     at https://superx-bcf15.web.app/:37:22
```

Comment: How much time have you spent researching the issue already?

It must be something to do with config, or the scope of what you're trying to view. 9/10 times while developing and seeing things like this, it's just being directed to the wrong place, or something hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages you provided are actually two separate errors.

#### The 404 Error

The first error message,

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

is caused by

```html
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

where the file `https://superx-bcf15.web.app/js/app.js` doesn't exist.

#### The Firebase '[DEFAULT]' app

```
firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:106 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call FirebaseApp.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
```

This error message indicates that you haven't called `firebase.initializeApp()` to pass in the required configuration parameters before trying to use the SDK elsewhere.

In your code, you try to call `firebase.auth()` before calling `firebase.initializeApp()` here:

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if(user){
            window.location.href = "admin.html";
        }
    });
</script>
```

You need to change that to

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    firebase.initializeApp(/* your firebase config here */);
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if(user){
            window.location.href = "admin.html";
        }
    });
</script>
```

These steps are well documented in the [Getting Started documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize).

Because you are using Firebase Hosting, you can also use the built-in helper script to call `initializeApp()` with the configuration needed for your project automatically (as you can [see here](https://superx-bcf15.web.app/__/firebase/init.js)):

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<script>
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if(user){
            window.location.href = "admin.html";
        }
    });
</script>
```